# PyGIWarning when sudo update-manager -d

Tags: update-manager, 16.04

Do I have some incomplete install?

```
$ sudo update-manager -d
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
sys:1: PyGIWarning: GdkX11 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are just warnings that should be fixed in `update-manager` code.

These warnings are just asking the Python code to specify a version during the library importing. But they're not errors and the program will work normally.